# I'm trying to replace a fragment in an Android app, but my fragment doesn't change (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am currently trying to get my app to open a fragment (with transitions) when a floating action button is clicked. However, while print statements in my function are running, the fragment that my app is displayed never changes. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

This is my code:

```kotlin
fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, istransition:Boolean) {
        val fragmentTransition = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        Log.d("replaceFragment", "The replaceFragment does run")

        if (istransition) {
            fragmentTransition.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left)
        }
        fragmentTransition.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
    }
```

```kotlin
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
                HomeFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    }
                }
    }
```

And I'm calling that function here, in my onViewCreated:

```
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        newEntryButton.setOnClickListener {
            replaceFragment(CreateJournalEntryFragment.newInstance(), true)
            Log.v("Red", "New journal entry test")
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `commit()` on your `FragmentTransaction`. Add one after `addToBackStack()`:

```
fragmentTransition
    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
    .commit()
```